# Limit of the sequence $(a_n)$ defined by $a_n=1+1/2+...+1/n-\int_1^n \frac{1}{t} dt$

Tags: real-analysis

What is the limit of the sequence $(a_n)$ defined by
$$a_n=1+1/2+...+1/n-\int_1^n \frac{1}{t} dt,$$
We see that $a_n$ is strictly decreasing sequence of non negative real numbers since $$\int_n^{n+1}\frac{1}{t}dt>\frac{1}{n+1},$$
and, graphically, it is a difference in some area and the area under the graph $y=\frac{1}{x}$, for $x>1$. I think the limit will be equal to $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1/n-\ln(1+1/n)),$$ But how to find the limit?

Comment: Look up Euler Mascheroni constant.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/euler-mascheroni-constant/info

Comment: Introduce the hamonic number to replace the sum and look at its asymptotics